# React - event.target is undefined when trying to filter React-select options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm pretty new to React and JavaScript, I'm trying to grab the value of a react-select dropdown option to use in a filter. The code below throws "Uncaught TypeError: event.target is undefined".

```
const [filter, setFilters] = useState({})

  const handleFilters = (event)=> {
    const value = event.target.value;
    setFilters({
      [event.target.name]: value,
    });
  };

  console.log(filter);
```

React-Select

```
<Select name="category" onChange={ handleFilters } options={filterOptions} className='dropdown'/>
```

React-Select Options

```
const filterOptions = [
    { value: 'value1', label: 'label1' },
    { value: 'value2', label: 'label2' },
    { value: 'value3', label: 'label3' },
    { value: 'value4', label: 'label4' }
  ];
```

the consolelog I'm expecting when choosing the first dropdown option would be -
{ category, value1 }

Comment: As the error says, `event` probably does not have a `target` property. Try using `event.value` instead, or just `console.log(event)` to see how it's structured.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because the **onChange** handler of react-select directly returns the option(Object) that is selected.

So, for example **event** will contain {label:"label1",value:"value1"}

You can have a look at this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-visvesvaraya-bidpf9?file=/src/App.js) for reference

Comment: This was it for me

Answer (score 0):

Please be advised that [react-select](https://react-select.com/home)'s `onChange` doesn't get called with the native select's onChange event but with the following [API](https://react-select.com/typescript#onchange):

```
const onChange = (option: Option | null, actionMeta: ActionMeta<Option>) => {
   ...
}
```

So your handler function should look like this

```
const handleFilters = (option) => {
  setFilters({
    [event.target.name]: option,
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the below change in the **onChange** event

```html
<Select name="category" onChange={(e)=> handleFilters(e) } options={filterOptions} className='dropdown'/>
```